# Do I only need the RPI 4B+ Board for the Crowpi2?

Tags: pi-4, laptop, pi-top

I'm thinking about getting the [Crowpi2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08NXHK2TV) (exact model) and I'm getting the basic kit, which does not include an RPI. What if I just get the Raspberry Pi board and the laptop? Do I need anything else? I already know there is no power bank included. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask Elecrow?  There are contact and community links on their webpage.  The big mystery there is the "32GB *TF* card with Customized System", although that there's also a "TF card reader" implies maybe you are supposed to use it as well as primary card (since AFAICT, "TF card" is nearly synonymous with "SD card" and should be useable with the built in slot).

Comment: @goldilocks I wasn't sure where to ask.

Comment: I didn't look, but there is a forum there.  It is probably pretty slow and you may have to wait a day but your question is fairly straightforward.  They'll almost certainly respond to an email request in about the same time period, do both.  If you get any details and no one answers here, please leave an answer of your own.